# Print integer as String in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

In Visual Basic,

I have the below code written but I have problem printing it in string format 
although it is type integer. I am trying to save time by not repeating the same 
thing for over 30 numbers.

```
Dim line As Integer
line = 0

Sub DisplayModule(page As Integer, line As Integer)
maxline = 100    
For line = 0 To maxline
Print #page, Spc(6); "Display in String"
Print #page, Spc(8); "{"
Print #page, Spc(10); """line"""
Print #page, Spc(8); "}"
Print #page, Spc(8); "next"
Next
End Sub
```

Problem -  It is displaying :

```
Display in String
{
 line
}
"next line please"
{
 line
}
.
.
```

I want it to display like this with "" :

```
Display in String
{
 "0"
}
"next line please"
{
 "1"
}
.
.
```

I couldn't find anything similar like this on SO.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Print #page, Spc(10); chr(34) & line & chr(34)
```

Comment: @PeterL. My Apologies for the inconvenience caused :P

Comment: my pleasure sir - I enjoy that race)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Dim line As Integer
line = 0

Sub DisplayModule(page As Integer, line As Integer)
   maxline = 100    
   For line = 0 To maxline
      Print #page, Spc(6); "Display in String"
      Print #page, Spc(8); "{"
      Print #page, Spc(10); """" & line & """"
      Print #page, Spc(8); "}" 
      Print #page, Spc(8); "next"
   Next
End Sub
```